# Dependency Injection in Model classes (entities)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I am building an ASP.NET Core MVC application with Entity Framework Code-First.
I implemented a simple repository pattern, providing basic CRUD operations for all the model classes I have created.
I chose to follow all the recommendations provided in [docs](http://docs.asp.net) and DI is one of these.

In ~~.NET 5~~ (*6 years later update: .net 5 was the alpha name of .net core 1.0*) dependency injection works very well for any class that we do not directly instantiate (e.g.: controllers, data repositories, ...).

We simply inject them via the constructor, and register the mappings in the Startup class of the application :

```cs
// Some repository class
public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
{
    private readonly IMyDependency _myDependency;
    public MyRepository(IMyDependency myDependency)
    {
        _myDependency = myDependency;
    }
}

// In startup.cs :
services.AddScoped<IMyDependency, MyDependency>();
services.AddScoped<IMyRepository, MyRepository>();
```

The problem is that in some of my model classes, I would like to inject some of the dependencies I have declared.

But I think that I cannot use the constructor injection pattern because model classes are often explicitly instantiated. Therefore, I would need to provide myself with the dependencies, which I can't.

So my question is: is there another way than constructor injection to inject dependencies, and how? I was for example thinking of an attribute pattern or something like that.

Comment: Since you are creating the models explicitly, there is no way for the DI framework to run for you and fill in dependencies, even if there was some pattern for it. That being said: What kind of dependency are we talking about? What do you need in your model instances?

Comment: Good rule of thumb: Never "new" anything up. Always have DI handle it for you. Suggested viewing: [Deep Dive into Dependency Injection and Writing Decoupled Quality Code and Testable Software](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B412)

Comment: I have created a simple configuration class, providing some hard coded values, used in logic methods of my model classes (ok, they do not directly concern the model), and would like to use a singleton instance of that class instead of instanciating it (even if the latter works fine). Beyond that simple example, I also felt the need of implementing business methods in my models that require instances of self or other data repositories.

Comment: @mason So you are saying that you don’t create model instances using `new` in your code? How do you create new models then, inject them via DI and hope that they are new objects? How do you get two new models of the same type?

Comment: @kall2sollies I think the repostory example in your question does not really help conveying your question about creating a *model* object and injecting a dependency in that. You might want to change your question so your actual intent becomes more clear.

Comment: You can inject a service resolver into your class. I'm not sure what the code looks like in ASP.NET 5, but in pseudo code it might be something like `IMyDependency newInstance = resolver.Resolve<IMyDependency>();`

Comment: Same problem, the resolver should be itself injected. @poke: the goal of the example was to remind how basic DI works in ASP.NET 5.

Comment: You can try property injections and a BuildUp service/help that will inspect your model/object looking for Properties that are Interfaces and call the DI to resolve the type and inject it into the model/object

Comment: @kall2sollies No, it doesn't have the same problem because my point is that ALL classes should be instantiated by the DI container, you should not new up classes, even models.

Comment: @kall2sollies: You are making something fundamentally wrong with your application design, if your model classes need mandatory dependencies. Try to elaborate **WHY** you need this dependencies in your models

Comment: @tseng: you make a point, this might be a design issue. Actually, everything that would require dependencies in my models can be achieved in my repositories (and this is what I currently do). Moving parts to model classes was in order to have a more fluent and functional reading of the code. This is more about cosmetics than blocking issue.

Comment: Generally you can use Method injection to inject a certain service (i.e. `IVatCalculator` into your model class via `order.CalculateVat(vatCalculator)`. The `IVatCalculator` could have a `public Currency Calculate(Currency currency, Country country) method to fetch tax rates from database and do the calculation based on the vat rate, th en return the calculated value and assign it inside your model. I could post an example as an answer on how you'd do it in an DDD centric way using one or more services if that's what you are trying to achieve by moving logic to models, called rich domain model

Comment: This is not the domain of my app (it's related to education) but the comparison with tax and exchange rates services is exactly the kind of reason why I could need service dependencies in my model classes.

Comment: Why not create it as a ProxyModel class let's say, just a model class that has a constructor that takes your DbContext as a constructor parameter and whatever other dependencies you need that you'll pass to it from the controller, then call that from your controller class so that it wraps up some logic that you want to keep behind the scenes to the controller? You don't want to interfere with any of the scaffolded classes from your data model so it's basically a layer between the controller and models I just call them ProxyModels for lack of a better word and put those in their own namespaces.

Comment: @JohnErnest As long as I can new the model classes myself, I think your model would work. But Entity Framework does new classes itself, calling their default parameterless constructor. In this case, a logic should be implemented to avoid errors when dependencies are not met.

Comment: @kall2sollies I’ve implemented exactly that over the past few days using ScaffoldDb from MSSQL to build the Model classes, and a “ProxyModel” namespace of classes that take a DbContext as a constructor parameter, so that I can wrap up a large amount of logic that touches the EF Core classes and have one simple constructor and method for each controller route. I even reference it in Startup.can/Configure with the IServiceProvider for code that needs to run once on server startup, works as expected.

Comment: @JohnErnest Do you think you could post your simplified solution as an answer to the question ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know my answer is late and may not exactly what you're asking for, but I wanted to share how I do it.

**First of all**: If you want to have a static class that resolves your dependencies this is a [ServiceLocator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) and it's [Antipattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) so try not to use it as you can.
In my case I needed it to call [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR) inside of my DomainModel to implement the [DomainEvents](http://udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/) logic.

**Anyway**, I had to find a way to call a static class in my DomainModel to get an instance of some registered service from DI.

So I've decided to use the `HttpContext` to access the `IServiceProvider` but I needed to access it from a static method without mention it in my domain model.

Let's do it:

1- I've created an interface to wrap the IServiceProvider

```
public interface IServiceProviderProxy
{
    T GetService<T>();
    IEnumerable<T> GetServices<T>();
    object GetService(Type type);
    IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type type);
}
```

2- Then I've created a static class to be my ServiceLocator access point

```
public static class ServiceLocator
{
    private static IServiceProviderProxy diProxy;

    public static IServiceProviderProxy ServiceProvider => diProxy ?? throw new Exception("You should Initialize the ServiceProvider before using it.");

    public static void Initialize(IServiceProviderProxy proxy)
    {
        diProxy = proxy;
    }
}
```

3- I've created an implementation for the `IServiceProviderProxy` which use internally the `IHttpContextAccessor`

```
public class HttpContextServiceProviderProxy : IServiceProviderProxy
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;

    public HttpContextServiceProviderProxy(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        this.contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    public T GetService<T>()
    {
        return contextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetServices<T>()
    {
        return contextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetServices<T>();
    }

    public object GetService(Type type)
    {
        return contextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(type);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type type)
    {
        return contextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetServices(type);
    }
}
```

4- I should register the `IServiceProviderProxy` in the DI like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddSingleton<IServiceProviderProxy, HttpContextServiceProviderProxy>();
    .......
}
```

5- Final step is to initialize the `ServiceLocator` with an instance of `IServiceProviderProxy` at the Application startup

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,IServiceProvider sp)
{
    ServiceLocator.Initialize(sp.GetService<IServiceProviderProxy>());
}
```

As a result now you can call the ServiceLocator in your DomainModel classes "Or and needed place" and resolve the dependencies that you need.

```
public class FakeModel
{
    public FakeModel(Guid id, string value)
    {
        Id = id;
        Value = value;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; }
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public async Task UpdateAsync(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
        var mediator = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMediator>();
        await mediator.Send(new FakeModelUpdated(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being also late to accept your answer! Since then, I also came to the point that ServiceLocator is EVIL, but maybe the only way to achieve this!

Answer (score 13):

As I already explained in a comment, when creating an object using `new`, there is nothing from the dependency injection framework that is involved in the process. As such, it’s impossible for the DI framework to magically inject things into that object, it simply doesn’t know about it.

Since it does not make any sense to let the DI framework *create* your model instances (models are not a *dependency*), you will have to pass in your dependencies explicitly if you want the model to have them. How you do that depends a bit on what your models are used for, and what those dependencies are.

The simple and clear case would be to just have your model expect the dependencies on the constructor. That way, it is a compile time error if you do not provide them, and the model has access to them right away. As such, whatever is above, creating the models, is required to have the dependencies the model type needs. But at that level, it’s likely that this is a service or a controller which has access to DI and can request the dependency itself.

Of course, depending on the number of dependencies, this might become a bit complicated as you need to pass them all to the constructor. So one alternative would be to have some “model factory” that takes care of creating the model object. Another alternative would also be to use the [service locator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern), passing the `IServiceCollection` to the model which can then request whatever dependencies it needs. Note that is generally a bad practice and not really inversion of control anymore.

Both these ideas have the issue that they modify the way the object is created. And some models, especially those handled by Entity Framework, need an empty constructor in order for EF to be able to create the object. So at that point you will probably end up with *some cases* where the dependencies of your model are *not* resolved (and you have no easy way of telling).

A generally better way, which is also a lot more explicit, would be to pass in the dependency where you need it, e.g. if you have some method on the model that calculates some stuff but requires some configuration, let the method require that configuration. This also makes the methods easier to test.

Another solution would be to move the logic out of the model. For example the [ASP.NET Identity models](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityUser.cs) are really dumb. They don’t do anything. All the logic is done in the [UserStore](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/UserStore.cs) which is a service and as such can have service dependencies.

Comment: This is in fact possible, as I have detailed in my answer. You can manually utilize the `CallContextServiceLocator.Locator.ServiceProvider` to resolve the dependency with a class that you manually instantiate.

Comment: @DavidPine That’s not dependency injection though. That is very ugly service locator pattern with a hard dependency to a static (global) object. Also, I have no idea what you are referring to with *“this”* in *“this is in fact possible”*. You make it appear as if my answer was two lines long.

Comment: Both are controlled by the adding of the `IInterface` to `Implementation` in the `Startup.cs`. And for all intensive purposes as it pertains to helping the OP getting what they are looking for, it is what they need as you called attention to "it's impossible".

Comment: @DavidPine This is not about where things are registered, it’s about how dependencies are resolved. To quote myself, it is “impossible for the DI framework to magically inject things into that object”. DI simply cannot do that. If you choose a completely different solution, which is not dependency injection and inversion of control, of course you can make this work in some way, but that doesn’t make this work with DI—it’s a completely different approach.

Comment: Thank you, I did see that. I did update my answer to say it's not DI and called attention to the "service locator pattern".

Comment: This answer is in my opinion a very good summary of what my problem is, and why it cannot have a solution by design. Models should be simple POCOS with no dependency at all. Any business logic related to them should be in their corresponding repo, or in ModelController classes, as MS Identity does with the UserStore. I cannot mark this answer as the solution, since there is no solution, so I will +1 your answer.

Answer (score 8):

The pattern often used in domain driven design (rich domain model to be specific) is to pass the required services into the method you are calling.

For example if you want to calculate the vat, you'd pass the vat service into the `CalculateVat` method.

In your model

```
    public void CalculateVat(IVatCalculator vatCalc) 
    {
        if(vatCalc == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(vatCalc));

        decimal vatAmount = vatcalc.Calculate(this.TotalNetPrice, this.Country);
        this.VatAmount = new Currency(vatAmount, this.CurrencySymbol);
    }
```

Your service class

```
    // where vatCalculator is an implementation IVatCalculator 
    order.CalculateVat(vatCalculator);
```

Finally your service can inject another services, like a repository which will fetch the tax rate for a certain country

```
public class VatCalculator : IVatCalculator
{
    private readonly IVatRepository vatRepository;

    public VatCalculator(IVatRepository vatRepository)
    {
        if(vatRepository == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(vatRepository));

        this.vatRepository = vatRepository;
    }

    public decimal Calculate(decimal value, Country country) 
    {
        decimal vatRate = vatRepository.GetVatRateForCountry(country);

        return vatAmount = value * vatRate;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would actually work if Entity Framework Code First knew how to handle injection of IVatCalculator. It requires parameter-less constructors.

Comment: @MilivojMilani: EF Core isn't involved in this. Entities shouldn't ever have constructor dependencies. As you can see from the first example the calculator is **injected into the method**  of the Model, not it's constructor. So in your order service, you **explicitly** call `order.CalculateVat(vatCalculator);` (`order` being your domain model) and pass the instance of the calculator. So EF/EFCore isn't involved in this process at all

Comment: Did you use this approach on your projects? If so, had it led to any issue?

Comment: @Gogo-the-Cat: Yea. Generally it works good. You'd have like an `IOrderService` which is a thing wrapper and contains some coordination logic (making sure the services are resolved and passed to the method), while the business logic is within your domain models. Instead of the `CalculateVat` method in practice one may pass the calculator to the `AddOrderPosition`, so the new positions are calculated the moment they are added, so it's not necessary to "remember" to call `CalculateVat` at the end and always ensure that the `Order` class is in a consistent state

Answer (score 1):

The built-in model binders complain that they cannot find a default ctor. Therefore you need a custom one.

You may find a solution to a similar problem [here](https://github.com/Serjster/IOCModelBinderExample/tree/ASPNETRTMVersion), which inspects the registered services in order to create the model.

It is important to note that the snippets below provide slightly different functionality which, hopefully, satisfies your particular needs. The code below expects models with ctor injections. Of course, these models have the usual properties you might have defined. These properties are filled in exactly as expected, so the bonus is **the correct behavior when binding models with ctor injections**.

```
    public class DiModelBinder : ComplexTypeModelBinder
    {
        public DiModelBinder(IDictionary<ModelMetadata, IModelBinder> propertyBinders) : base(propertyBinders)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the model with one (or more) injected service(s).
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bindingContext"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected override object CreateModel(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var services = bindingContext.HttpContext.RequestServices;
            var modelType = bindingContext.ModelType;
            var ctors = modelType.GetConstructors();
            foreach (var ctor in ctors)
            {
                var paramTypes = ctor.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToList();
                var parameters = paramTypes.Select(p => services.GetService(p)).ToArray();
                if (parameters.All(p => p != null))
                {
                    var model = ctor.Invoke(parameters);
                    return model;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

This binder will be provided by:

```
public class DiModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context)); }

        if (context.Metadata.IsComplexType && !context.Metadata.IsCollectionType)
        {
            var propertyBinders = context.Metadata.Properties.ToDictionary(property => property, context.CreateBinder);
            return new DiModelBinder(propertyBinders);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Here's how the binder would be registered:

```
services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(options =>
{
    // replace ComplexTypeModelBinderProvider with its descendent - IoCModelBinderProvider
    var provider = options.ModelBinderProviders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(ComplexTypeModelBinderProvider));
    var binderIndex = options.ModelBinderProviders.IndexOf(provider);
    options.ModelBinderProviders.Remove(provider);
    options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(binderIndex, new DiModelBinderProvider());
});
```

I'm not quite sure if the new binder must be registered exactly at the same index, you can experiment with this.

And, at the end, this is how you can use it:

```
public class MyModel 
{
    private readonly IMyRepository repo;

    public MyModel(IMyRepository repo) 
    {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    ... do whatever you want with your repo

    public string AProperty { get; set; }

    ... other properties here
}
```

Model class is created by the binder which supplies the (already registered) service, and the rest of the model binders provide the property values from their usual sources.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

> Is there another way than constructor injection to inject dependencies, and how?

The answer is "no", this cannot be done with "dependency injection". But, "yes" you can use the "service locator pattern" to achieve your end-goal.

You can use the code below to resolve a dependency without the use of constructor injection or the `FromServices` attribute. Additionally you can `new` up an instance of the class as you see fit and it will still work -- assuming that you have added the dependency in the `Startup.cs`.

```
public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
{
    public IMyDependency { get; } =
        CallContextServiceLocator.Locator
                                 .ServiceProvider
                                 .GetRequiredService<IMyDependency>();
}
```

The `CallContextServiceLocator.Locator.ServiceProvider` is the global service provider, where everything lives. It is not really advised to use this. But if you have no other choice you can. It would be recommended to instead use **DI** all the way and never manually instantiate an object, i.e.; avoid `new`.

Comment: This actually doesn’t make any difference from OP’s code in this example since the repository is also injected via DI. OP was actually asking about a *model* class in which they want to inject a dependency.

Comment: As said in previous comment, [FromServices] is an alternative to constructor injection for a class that is itself resolved by DI. But in the question comments, @poke pointed out the fact that model class are by design explicitely instanciated, which is the origin of my problem.

Comment: This is not dependency injection, this is the [service locator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) which is *very* different from DI and does couple the class very hard to a static type, making it very hard to test and defeating the whole purpose of inversion of control.

Comment: This answer actually provides a solution, but the solution breaks design rules (POCO should finally be just POCOs) and injects strong coupling with a pattern that should be avoided. Thanks for taking time to it, I cannot mark this answer as accepted, but I have +1-ed it.

Comment: @kall2sollies: Even if its old, I just now noticed the `[FromService]` comment. It doesn't work that way. `[FromService]` can only be used in Controller Actions and ever since rc2 it is limited to method parameters, because people confused it and tried to use it for a generic method/property injection

Comment: @Tseng: that question is pretty old since it was about dnx, and things have changed until dotnet 1.1 (dotnet 2 is coming !). But you are right about your comment, and I now try to avoid things like this. Since controllers fully support constructor DI, I think it is more consistent to use this pattern even in controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm simply adding some supplemental information here to the answers provided that can help.

IServiceProvider was provided in the accepted answer, but not the important IServiceProvider.CreateScope() method. You can use it to create scopes as necessary that you added through ConfigureServices.

I'm not sure if IServiceProvider is actually a Service Locator pattern behind the scenes or not, but it's how you create scopes as far as I know. At least in the case if it is a Service Locator pattern, it's the official one for today in .NET, and so it's not compounded by the problems of writing your own Service Locator, which I also agree is anti-pattern.

Example, Startup.cs/ConfigureServices and Configure:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<SomeDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetSection("Databases").GetSection("SomeDb")["ConnectionString"]);
            options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
        }, ServiceLifetime.Scoped);

        services.AddMvcCore().AddNewtonsoftJson();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        ...
        IServiceScope scope = provider.CreateScope();
        SomeDbContext context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SomeDbContext>();
        SomeModelProxyClass example = new SomeModelProxyClass(context);
        await example.BuildDefaults(
            Configuration.GetSection("ProfileDefaults").GetSection("Something"),
            Configuration.GetSection("ProfileDefaults").GetSection("SomethingSomething"));
        scope.Dispose();
    }
```

The above is for doing some default interactions on Startup, maybe if you need to build some default records in your database on a first usage, just as an example.

Ok so let's get to your repository and dependency though, will they work?

Yep!

Here's a test in my own CRUD project, I made a simple minimalist implementation of your IMyDependency and IMyRepository like so, then added them scoped as you did to Startup/ConfigureServices:

```
public interface IMyRepository
{
    string WriteMessage(string input);
}

public interface IMyDependency
{
    string GetTimeStamp();
}

public class MyDependency : IMyDependency
{
    public MyDependency()
    {

    }

    public string GetTimeStamp()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
}

public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
{
    private readonly IMyDependency _myDependency;
    public MyRepository(IMyDependency myDependency)
    {
        _myDependency = myDependency;
    }

    public string WriteMessage(string input)
    {
        return input + " - " + _myDependency.GetTimeStamp();
    }
}
```

Here ContextCRUD is a Model class from my own project not derived from Scaffold-DbContext tooling like my other database classes, it's a container of logic from those scaffold Model classes, and so I put it in the namespace Models.ProxyModels to hold its own business logic for doing CRUD operations so that the Controllers are not gummed up with logic that should be in the Model:

```
    public ContextCRUD(DbContext context, IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        Context = context;
        Provider = provider;

        var scope = provider.CreateScope();
        var dep1 = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMyRepository>();
        string msg = dep1.WriteMessage("Current Time:");
        scope.Dispose();
    }
```

Debugging I get back the expected results in msg, so it all checks out.

The calling code from the Controller for reference, just so you can see how IServiceProvider is passed from upstream by constructor injection in the Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class GenericController<T> : Controller where T: DbContext
{
    T Context { get; set; }
    ContextCRUD CRUD { get; set; }
    IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public GenericController(T context, IConfiguration configuration, IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        Context = context;
        CRUD = new ContextCRUD(context, provider);
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do it, check out [InjectionMethod] and container.BuildUp(instance);

Example:

> Typical DI constructor (NOT NEEDED IF YOU USE InjectionMethod) public
>   ClassConstructor(DeviceHead pDeviceHead) {
>       this.DeviceHead = pDeviceHead; }
>
> This attribute causes this method to be called to setup DI.
>   [InjectionMethod]  public void Initialize(DeviceHead pDeviceHead)  {
>       this.DeviceHead = pDeviceHead; }

Comment: Could you provide a simple code snippet, so that the answers on this thread are all consistent ?

Comment: public ClassConstructor(DeviceHead pDeviceHead)
        {
            this.DeviceHead = pDeviceHead;
        }



        [InjectionMethod]
        public void Initialize(DeviceHead pDeviceHead)
        {
            this.DeviceHead = pDeviceHead;
        }