# How to force the use of a domain service?

Tags: domain-driven-design, aspnetboilerplate

In your online documentation regarding domain services ("https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Domain-Services") you have section called "How do we force to use of the Domain Service?"

In there you imply that there is a lot of external documentation around the concept of injecting a kind of "policy" service into the entity as a way to do this, but the artice is kind of vague on the implementation of that class, along with where it should be injected and how it is used.   I have been scouring the Internet for examples of this kind of design to force the use of domain services, but haven't been able to find anything.

Just browsing that documentation leaves too many questions..

Additionally, I was hoping I could find a simple implementation of an Abp that provided an example of this, but could not find anything.

I'm very curious about this because I have found it to be a big problem with large projects in the past:  developers writing their own code in the application service layer, not knowing that the capabilities were already provided in some domain driven "Manager" service.

Can you provide a quick small sample of this concept fully implemented? Using Abp would be great, but a generic example would be fine as well.

take care,

jasen

Comment: You can make `AssignToPerson` `internal` so that it can only be called by the domain service.

Comment: You can always use method injection, i.e. `order.CalculateTax(taxServiceProvider)` where the `ITaxServiceProvider` may have a method called `GetTaxCalculatorFor(Country country, State state, TaxCode taxCode)` or something like that. So in order to calcualte the taxes you have to apss an instance of the TaxProvider which resolves a country specific tax calculation service. Since its all encapsulated within your aggregate root, it is mandatory to pass the service to the method (you have to make sure via encapsulation that i.e. Tax values can't be set from outside the aggregate)

Comment: Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36222407/455493) for a more concrete example.

Comment: Thanks Tseng.  The more I consider it, the more I'd like to stay away from requiring the entities to be aware of external services.  I was willing to do something simple and generic like a policy that allows setting properties, but fundamentally I don't like the idea of injecting dependencies into my entities.  Currently weighing pros and cons of just using "internal".

Comment: Well yea, your aggregates (not entities!!!) will have these external dependencies, but its the only way to really encapsulate specific logic. Otherwise there is no means you could i.e. add a position to an order and be sure that it remains in an consistent state. If in the above case you make the calculations external, you risk with inconsistent state (i.e. by passing wrong parameters to the method which calculates it).

Comment: With Method injection, the parameters will be passed from within the aggregate i.e. using a double dispatch pattern: The method calls the service with values available within the aggregate and sets an internal value which can't be set from outside. Since it can't be changed from outside, its consistency is guaranteed and it can't be set in an inconsistent state by mistake of one of the developers using the aggregate or the domain service. Imho consistency of an aggregate state is way more important than the fact that you have to inject the services into it.

Comment: For pure reading of the aggregate you don't need to inject anything, its only there for mutating it and since the tax can't (or may not be, since taxes can change) be calculated from the aggregate alone the an dependency is the only way to ensure this consistency

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

- The Policy pattern in that code plays no role in forcing use of the domain service. It is only making task assignment more modular and more SRP compliant.
- There's only so much defensive programming can do for you. Sure, making `AssignedPersonId` protected so that it cannot be directly assigned is a good thing, but a programmer could just as well change it back to public. Don't rely too much on technical code to prevent bad developer behavior - shared practices and team culture are much more efficient.
- Questioning application sample or template code (as you do) is sound. Don't take that code as gospel truth - it was never meant to be exemplary in the first place. Try your own stuff and learn from your mistakes. Experience is not something that can be transmitted through such a document.

Comment: I agree and appreciate the response.  I liked the idea of passing a "policy" like object into the entity that only the domain class had access to though.  I thought that was a nice trick, and if it was some kind of design principle I had never stumbled upon I wanted to read up some more on it, or see it implemented.  I couldn't find anything anywhere which I why I asked.

Comment: Thinking about it, I guess the policy is more of a [Specification pattern](https://martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf) - although "policy" probably fits that particular domain better.

Comment: Actually in the Abp projects, they implement their domain classes in the same assembly as the entity object themselves, so using internal on the properties seems like the simplest solution.  Not sure why that didn't hit me late last night :-)  Curious if there's any opinions on that?  As usual, I see conflicting opinions on that debate.