# Dependency injection into model in C# using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, dependency-injection

I'm using dependency injection for the first time and I have some problems with that.

Because of the single responsibility principle I have a an entity class and a collection class of the entity.

- The entity class (`user`) can only update itself
- The collection class (`userContainer`) can add, remove and getall users

I can inject into the container class because I don't have properties that needs to be defined in the constructor.

```cs
public class UserCollection : IUserCollection
{
    private readonly IUserCollectionDAL _userDAL;

    public UserCollection(IUserCollectionDAL userDAL)
    {
        _userDAL = userDAL;
    }
}
```

So this works fine. but in the following situation it's not working fine:

```cs
public class User 
{
     private IProjectCollection ProjectCollection;

     public int UserId { get; set; }
     public string Role { get; set; }
     public string Username { get; set; }
     public string Email { get; set; }

    public User(/*inject projectCollection not working ,*/int userId, string username, string email, string role)
    {
        this.UserId = userId;
        this.Role = role;
        this.Username = username;
        this.Email = email;
    }
}
```

This is not working because if I want to create a user, I need to inject the new `projectCollection`.

Startup.cs:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddScoped<IBugCollectionDAL, BugDAL>();
     services.AddScoped<IProjectCollectionDAL, ProjectDAL>();
     services.AddScoped<IUserCollectionDAL, UserDAL>();

     services.AddScoped<IBugCollection, BugCollection>();
     services.AddScoped<IProjectCollection, ProjectCollection>();
     services.AddScoped<IUserCollection, UserCollection>();

     services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

Any idea how to inject into a model with properties?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dependency Injection in Model classes (entities)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207289/dependency-injection-in-model-classes-entities)

Comment: Could you show us your ProjectCollection pls?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a default constructor too

```
public User () {}
```

It's a better coding  style to move your extra code  in  partial class

```
public partial class User
{
   public   User(IProjectCollection projectCollection ,int userId, string username, 
   string  email, string role)
   {
       this.UserId = userId;
       this.Role = role;
       this.Username = username;
       this.Email = email;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you create new instances in some of your classes and you want IOC-container to inject dependencies into new instance, that means you need to use factory - either factory method, or factory class which is injected by IOC.
For example, constructor of UserCollection:

```cs
    UserCollection(Func<User> userFactory)
```

And when you need to create User, you call this func and get IOC-injected instance. Can't say for your container, but Unity will resolve such function automatically - no registration is needed.
But, in your case you need parameterized constructor - so you need a factory class.
For example:

```cs
public class User {
   public class Factory {
      private IProjectCollection projects;
      public Factory(IProjectCollection projects) {
         this.project = projects;
      }
      public User Create(...) => new User(projects, ...);
  }
}

public class UserCollection {
   public UserCollection (User.Factory userFactory) { ... }
}
```

And now use userFactory.Create to instantiate User.
Again if container is Unity this doesn't require any registration, for other containers I can't tell.